# How to add bootstrap in Eclipse for jsp pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, eclipse-plugin

I'm having problem while including Bootstrap.jar lib in my eclipse project. I'm unable to access it in my JSP page.

Can anyone help me out so that i can access it in my jsp page.

Comment: r u using any MVC framework like struts 2 or spring MVc?

Comment: no. I'm not using any framework

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you download the files from bootstrap (css, js, ing) and add it to the project like this http://vitalflux.com/get-started-bootstrap-ui-eclipse/. It is simpler

Comment: I found it, we can add all bootstrap libraries in lib folder of web-inf

Answer (score 2):

download BootStrap from this link http://getbootstrap.com/ and copy the file in your project main/resources/static

The below tutorials has step by steps for that.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#overview

Answer (score 0):

Download bootstrap from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/
save it as bootstrap
it contain css,js,font folder containing all the code required for using bootstrap
now go to eclipse
1> create project give name and finish.
2> right click on created project create new file which u required(html,php,jsp) 
3> after the successful completion of creating file,right click on file u created select import->General->File system->double click file system->browse->select the folder which u downloaded and saved as bootstrap.
4> use link for css (<link  rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-min.css">)in head section.
5> for script in head section (<script type="text/javascript" src="boostrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" >) save and run the file.